# C++ getting struct from vector with & returns pointer to non-initialized struct

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

The function `structFromVector()` returns a struct from a vector of structs. If you compile the code below, then `foo1Ptr->a` is an empty vector, but `foo2Ptr->a` is a vector whose only element is 1. Why isn't the struct initialized in the first case?

If `a` is an int instead of a vector and instead of `a.push_back(1);` you use `a = 1;`, then both `foo1Ptr->a` and `foo2Ptr->a` are equal to 1. Why does it work in this case and not in the first case?

```
struct Foo {
    std::vector<int> a;

    Foo() {
        a.push_back(1);
    }
};

std::vector<Foo> fooList;

Foo structFromVector() {
    return fooList[0];
}

int main() {
    fooList.push_back(Foo());

    Foo * foo1Ptr = &structFromVector();

    Foo foo2 = structFromVector();
    Foo * foo2Ptr = &foo2;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, `&structFromVector()` is not valid in C++. Get a better compiler.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have *undefined behavior* in your code.

Here:

```
Foo * foo1Ptr = &structFromVector();
```

`structFromVector` returns a temp object and `foo1Ptr` becomes a pointer to this temp object. After `;`, this temp object is destroyed and the pointer is called *dangling* (in other words - it becomes invalid).

In the second case,

```
Foo foo2 = structFromVector();
Foo * foo2Ptr = &foo2;
```

`foo2` is now a *copy* of this temp object and `foo2Ptr` points to this copy. So, the pointer is valid (while `foo1Ptr` is invalid). The *copy* will be *alive* till the end of the scope - in this case, till `main`'s `}`.

The reason it "works" with `int` is, again, the UB (Undefined Behavior) - anything can happen.

---

**EDIT** Well, it appears to be ill-formed code, as the compiler really should have rejected that code. But as it hasn't, it's still UB.

Comment: It's actually ill-formed, the compiler should have rejected it instead of compiling something with undefined behaviour. Bad compiler.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - indeed. It just may be an old one, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to initialize a pointer with a temporary `Foo` object here:

```
Foo * foo1Ptr = &structFromVector();
```

Your compiler should have rejected this code (taking the address of a temporary.)

If it were to compile, after this line, one could imagine that `foo1Ptr` would point to a non-existent object (it would be a *dangling pointer*). Do de-reference it would invoke undefined behaviou. Still, discussing what a non-conforming implementation would do is quite speculative.

So, don't bind a pointer to a temporary, even if your compiler lets you do it.

One solution, which is probably what you were intending to do, is to return a reference to the vector's element:

```
Foo& structFromVector() {
    return fooList[0];
}
```

This reference is valid as long as you don't perform an operation on the vector that invalidates it (e.g. increasing its size such that it re-allocates.)